# Android: how to programmatically send command to Nonin OnyxII 9560 pulse oximeter to select the data format and display the SpO2 and heart rate value

Tags: android, bluetooth, dataformat

I am developing an Android Application of elder healthcare. The devices I used are Nonin Onyx II 9560 pulse oximeter and Nexus 7 tablet.

The application will allow the pulse oximeter and tablet to communicate with each other. Once the user makes a measurement with pulse oximeter, the reading will transmit to tablet via bluetooth.

I have already completed the connection session, but I don't know how to send command to pulse oximeter, to select the data format and after receiving, how to display the reading of SpO2 and heart rate on the tablet.

My application is quite similar to the [Simple Eye application](http://simpleeye.com/platforms/android/live-pulse-oximeter/).

I have found someone faces the same problem as me, however he solved his problem by using the code in [this website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402291/parsing-data-from-hdp-device-for-android-api-15). The code is for a blood pleasure sensor.

The following codes are from my app service class. I didn't purchase the development kit for Nonin Onyx II 9560.

Can anyone help me with these problems. Please provide me some ideas or help me modify my codes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question would get more attention if it would be more focused and specific. "I don't know how to send command to pulse oximeter to select the data format" - are you missing information about the command protocol or general information about sending data over Bluetooth? "How to display the reading of SpO2 and heart rate on the tablet" - Android provides lot of possiblities, this is too general to answer when we do not even know the exact nature of the data. This is actually too separate questions, and would work better to split this to two separate SO questions.

Comment: Hi FooF, thanks for your command. Actually my project is quite big and complex. I cannot explain it in detail. For Nonin Onyx ii 9560, there are 4 data format solutions which are Data format 13,8,2 and 7. Before receiving the acutal Spo2 and heart rate reading from pulse oximeter, the android device must send the 9560 the 6 bytes command to select data format, for example, If i want to use the data format 13, Android device need to send [0x02 0x70 0x02 0x02 0x0D 0x03] to 9560. I don't know how to send this command programmatically because i am quite new to Java.

Comment: Hello user2130557, I am trying to create a similar kind of app on iPhone but I am stuck with the bluetooth connection itself. It would be great if you could throw some pointers on how to connect the device with bluetooth ? What code is required to do that , if you could share the connection code that you did for android it would be appreciable. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

You will most likely need to purchase the [Development Kit](http://www.nonin.com/documents/M-3809%209560%20Development%20Kit%20Order%20Form.pdf) from the manufacturer

Comment: so u mean only by purchasing the development kit, i can develop the app?

Comment: actually i only bought the pulse oximeter and its brochure. I also find a specification for the pulse oximeter, pls visit http://www.nonin.cz/ceniky/cenik-7-1248786286.pdf.

Comment: I didn't brought the development kit.

Comment: I am waiting for your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I changed two places and got new record but not all records.

1. obj_handle
2. byteToUnsignedInt(data[packet_start+5]); // The 5 is found in DataReporting(Page67 of the IEEE Std 11073-10404)

Answer (score 0):

If it is anything like the Nonin WristOx, I suggest that you learn how to send Hex commands through a PC terminal like Termie or OSX CoolTerm.  The protocol should be in the publicly available documentation (it was available for the WristOx)  Once you have mastered this, then you can adapt it to other platforms (Android).

There are good examples in Github.