# Converting Bluetooth SPP commands into HDP ones

Tags: android, health-monitoring, spp

I'm developing an app for android that retrives the data from an oximeter (the model is  [this](http://www.nonin.com/products.asp?ID=39&sec=2&sub=9)) using the HDP profile that API14 provide. I'm able to retrive the data and convert it into a human readable format, thanks to a post I've read on this forum ([This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10402291/parsing-data-from-hdp-device-for-android-api-15?lq=1)). The problem is that I'd like to set the date and/or retrive other informations from the oximeter (on the [instruction manual](http://www.nonin.cz/ceniky/cenik-7-1248786286.pdf) I've read that is possible to set/get the date, to get the Revision number, serial number and model number). The main issue is that the manual explains the commands using the SPP protocol: for example, on page 4 (page 8, if you are looking from the pdf) it says:

> The host can set and retrieve the time from the 9560. The date and time must conform to the ranges defined below. The
>   date and time will be lost when replacing the batteries.
>   Setting the Time: To set the time in the 9560 the host must send the 9560 a 10 byte command.Byte 1 Byte2 Byte3 Byte4 Byte5 Byte6 Byte7 Byte8 Byte9 Byte10 Start(STX) Op Code Data Size Year Month Day Hour Minute Second ETX
>   0x02 0x72 0x06 YY MM DD hh mm ss 0x03

How could I convert this SPP command [0x02 0x72 0x06 0x0D 0x06 0x09 0x14 0x0E 0x00] into an HDP one? Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help!